# Prevent method call using compiler tricks

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have roughly these types:

```
interface Record {}
interface UpdatableRecord extends Record {}

interface Insert<R extends Record> {

    // Calling this method only makes sense if <R extends UpdatableRecord>
    void onDuplicateKeyUpdate();
}
```

I would like to have an additional restriction on `<R>` when calling `onDuplicateKeyUpdate()`. The reason for this is that this method only makes sense, when `<R>` is bound to any subtype of `UpdatableRecord`, not just `Record`. Examples:

```
Insert<?>               i1;
Insert<Record>          i2;
Insert<UpdatableRecord> i3;

// these shouldn't compile
i1.onDuplicateKeyUpdate();
i2.onDuplicateKeyUpdate();

// this should compile
i3.onDuplicateKeyUpdate();
```

Is there any trick or way that I can use to add an additional restriction for the class' generic type just for one method declaration?

**NOTE**:

- Declaring `Insert<R extends UpdatableRecord>` is not an option, because I want the flexibility of having an `Insert<R extends Record>` for records that are not updatable
- Deriving `UpdatableInsert<R extends UpdatableRecord> extends Insert<R>` and pushing the method down there might be an option, but I don't really want to introduce a new type. I have several of these methods with several different restrictions, which would lead to a type explosion.
- Throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is quite obvious, but it seems the Java 1.4 way of doing it. I really wonder if I can use generics and the compiler for this issue.

**Ideal solution**:

```
// This would be an annotation to be interpreted by the compiler. There is no such
// thing in Java, as far as I know. But maybe there's a trick having the same effect?
@Require(R extends UpdatableRecord)
void onDuplicateKeyUpdate();
```

Comment: Would it be an option to remove `onDupliceteKeyUpdate()` from interface `Insert` and derive a second one `interface UpdatableInsert<R extends UpdatableRecord> extends Insert<R>` redefining `void onDuplicateKeyUpdate();`?

Comment: Why not just declare interface Insert to be <R extends UpdateableRecord>? If this isn't possible, then what you ask isn't possible unless you do something like what Howard suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I'll update my question

Answer (score 4):

If you're defining it in the interface, then it must be implemented in any class that wishes to implement the interface. So there is no way you can get around implementing `onDuplicateKeyUpdate` in any class that implements the `Insert<R extends Record>` interface.

You've specified that `R extends Record` in the interface and so this becomes part of the contract, which means that any subtype of `Record` can be used. I can't think of a way to add an additional constraint using generics that restricts it to only of type `UpdatableRecord`.

Also, you cannot make decisions in your interface based on the type of `R` because that information goes away due to type erasure.

It seems to me that your problem revolves around the difference between `Record` and `UpdatableRecord`. Since an interface is meant to be general contract, I don't think that type-specific behavior should be in your interface. So you would have to figure out a way to resolve the difference another way. My solution would be to implement a method (that returns `boolean`) in the `Record` interface called `canUpdate` that you can use in `onDuplicateKeyUpdate`. This way you can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the record doesn't support that operation or do nothing (if you want to avoid the exception, and if doing nothing makes sense in the context of your business logic).

This is off the top of my head; there may be a better solution. I'll try to think about it some more.

**EDIT**

I thought about this a little more and it was your latest edit that made me think about this. The `<R extends Record>` applies to the entire class. So there's no way to override or narrow it down in the context of a specific method. An annotation like the one you mentioned needs to be implemented at the compiler level and at that level I'm not even sure if you will have access to the type of R (because of type erasure). So what you're saying may not be possible.

On a conceptual level, what you're asking for *shouldn't* be possible IMO because you're specifying an exception to the contract *within* your contract. It also sounds like implementation details are creeping into your interface because the interfaces shouldn't try to figure out what something can or cannot do; that should be decided in the concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't need to add any additional methods or checks to be able to throw `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`. That's the simplest way of doing it, along with some documentation in the Javadoc. But I thought maybe there is a way to do it on a compiler (and thus much safer) level

Answer (score 1):

Vivin makes a good point about the contract you made when you created `Insert`.  I would question whether `onDuplicateKeyUpdate()` really makes sense in that context.  It seems rather specific to only one subtype of `Record`.

If you can roll that functionality into another `Insert` method (say `execute()`?), you can test the type of the object there and act accordingly.  For example,

```
[pseudo-code]
method execute( R record )
 try
  insertRecord( record )
 catch ( KeyAlreadyExistsException e )
  if ( record instanceof UpdatableRecord )
   updateRecord( record )
  end if
 end try
end method
```

If you're looking for a more object-oriented approach, you could push the logic for an insert into the `Record` subclasses themselves.  There, I would change `Insert` to `Insertable`, give it an `insert()` method, and have `Record` implement `Insertable`.  Then each subclass of `Record` could know the proper way to `insert()` itself.  I'm not sure if that fits with your design strategy though...

Comment: @Mike, thanks for your input. That makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, my example is too abstract to truly describe my "real-life problem". In fact, I'm not updating `R`, but a database table of type `R`. `onDuplicateKeyUpdate()` is really part of a larger DSL for modelling SQL in Java. And it is a clause that shouldn't be used if `R` is not `UpdatableRecord`... Hard to put in a few words, though :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; that certainly frames the question differently.  So it sounds like `onDuplicateKeyUpdate()` is called by external software on an insert when there exists a duplicate key.  Is that right?  It's essentially a callback method?

Comment: Yes, external software calls that method. It's much more than that. You can really model SQL in Java as if it were an embedded DSL (kind of like LINQ to SQL in C#). Find some examples here: https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/wiki/Manual/DSL/SELECT

Comment: So you're writing an API for this DSL that allows its users to string SQL-like syntax in Java.  (Very cool!)  This particular case is an insert statement, one of the SQL clauses for which is "on duplicate key update".  If you validate the query before submitting it to whatever you're using as a database, then you must need access to the `Class<R>` object as a member of `Insert<R>` anyway, yes?  In that case, you can throw a checked exception if the method is called inappropriately.  By making it a checked exception, the user knows he has to be careful.  Does that sound like your situation?

Comment: You got it! I am currently throwing a checked exception, but I'd prefer a compile-time check. The compiler has all the necessary information. I just don't know if there is a trick (note: trick. I don't think Java was designed for these things) to let the compiler formally check these things.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the Java compiler or annotations to be of much help.  I think you're on the right track with annotations if what you're looking for is indeed possible.  One last question comes to mind: does the C# version result in a compile error in your situation?  If so, what technique do they use?  Bear in mind that a user might not actually expect a compile error, since they wouldn't necessarily know about a SQL error until runtime.  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  I'm definitely going to keep my eye on this topic to see if there's a resolution.

Comment: @Mike, don't worry. It's a tricky question and I epect the answer to be *no*. I don't know much about C#. LINQ to SQL does not support such advanced SQL constructs, natively...